# LWC Lightning Data Table - Save All Records(Rows) in the Table upon Save Button Click

Tags: lightning-web-components, datatable

I have a requirement to be able to save all records present in the Editable Lightning data table and not just the ones that are edited. Is there a way yo achieve this.
I see we can only fetch the drat values and not all the rows/records on Save

Please assist

Comment: The data that you put into table is all rows/records "data={data}".

Comment: Thanks for the reply . I require to fetch all the rows on the save handler function and want to manipulate some field value on this records and save all the records:  Here is the save handler :   async handleSave(event) {
        const updatedFields = event.detail.draftValues;

Comment: Yes, however when I validate the {data} on Save handler, it only contains the original data and not the modified one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

possible solution could look like (id is a key-field)

```
handleSave(event) {
    const updatedRecords = event.detail.draftValues

    const updatedData = this.data.map(row => {
        const newRow = Object.assign({}, row);
        const changes = updatedRecords.find(changedElement => changedElement.id === row.id);
        return changes ? Object.assign(newRow, changes) : newRow;
    });

    console.log(updatedData);
}
```

You need to merge `draftValues` with the `original data`, therefore you will have all records with changes

Thanks

Comment: Thank you much. This works perfectly fine. It satisfies my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

For fetching all the rows in the table, we need to get 'data' attribute

A modified version of your code to fetch data from table

```
handleSave(event)
{
const updatedFields = event.detail.data;
<your rest of the code logic>
}
```

lightning datatable documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/specification

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This gives me the full data to look into